# Rename indirectly in R

Tags: r, rename, plyr

I want to use `rename()` from package `plyr` to rename a column in a dataframe in R:

```
mtcars <- rename(mtcars, c("disp"="displacement"))
```

What if I want to store `"disp"` in a variable itself?

```
var <- "disp"
mtcars <- rename(mtcars, c(var="displacement"))
```

not possible:

```
The following `from` values were not present in `x`: var
```

I'd say it's important to be able to rename indirectly, at least in loops. Is there something to use the content of `var` in `rename()`? I can't believe `names(mtcars)[names(mtcars)==var] <- "displacement"` is the only possibility at hand?!

Comment: `names(mtcars)[names(mtcars)==var] <- "displacement"` seems fine to me. Of course, package data.table syntax is nicer: `setnames(mtcars, var, "displacement")`. Copying a data.frame just to rename a column is not really efficient, so I wouldn't use `plyr::rename` for this.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that `setnames()` was available. This completely solves the problem. Want to provide an answer, such that I can mark the question as resolved?